# R - Convert a column of factors into binary characters without loss of information

Tags: r, character, printf

I am very new to R and just teaching myself how to use it. I'm using R version 3.0.1 on Windows 7 (if that's relevant).

I have trouble converting data of `factor`s into only characters. My data is as follows:

```
activity <- c("1","2","10","ZZ")
```

What I want to have as output is

```
activity <- c("01","02","10","ZZ")
```

where, each string, if only contains one character, should be prefixed by a `0` (as shown above).

I tried using "as.character" but that doesn't add a zero before. Then I found `sprintf` and tried:

```
activity <- sprintf("%02d", (activity))
# [1] "01" "02" "03" "04"
```

This adds a zero "0" in front of any single data found but what's troublesome is that it modifies all levels of the data (as shown above).

Does anybody know what's wrong here and how I can fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions, particularly the function `sub` to replace any *single digit* with a `0` followed by that digit. You should do this to replace the levels of your factor `activity` so that the whole data is changed accordingly:

```
levels(activity) <- sub("^([0-9])$", "0\\1", levels(activity))
# [1] 01 02 10 ZZ
# Levels: 01 02 10 ZZ
```

---

Edit: If you want to not just replace numbers but any string with just 1 character, then you can just replace `[0-9]` with `.`. That is:

```
# suppose x is:
x <- c("1", "a", "Y", "!", "bb", "45") 
x <- factor(x, levels=unique(x))

levels(x) <- sub("^(.)$", "0\\1", levels(x))
# [1] 01 0a 0Y 0! bb 45
# Levels: 01 0a 0Y 0! bb 45
```

Comment: Hi, I just want to prefix single digits with "0" then turn it into character string but leave the already character strings as it is. Given that normally, they already match the length limit of my data which is = 2. I'm gonna try sub as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, it works fine but I'm not sure to understand "0\\1" does it have something to do with backreferences?

Comment: `\\1` captures whatever is matched within parenthesis. That is, whatever string matched `([0-9])`.

Answer (score 2):

Read `?factor` for the proper way to convert factors back to their values.  You need to be cautious about manipulating factors as you've seen since sometimes you will wind up altering the underlying index rather than the `level` of the factor.

Also, you also cannot "zero pad" characters:

```
y <- factor(c('1', '2', '10', 'ZZ'))
x <- as.character(y)
sprintf('%02d', x)
Error in sprintf("%02d", x) : 
  invalid format '%02d'; use format %s for character objects
```

Instead, you could use a yucky `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(x)), x, sprintf('%02d', as.numeric(x)))
[1] "01" "02" "10" "ZZ"
```

But as Arun has shown, regular expressions are the way to go here!